# Solve the Partial Defferential Equation $z+xp-x^2 y q^2-x^3 p q=0$, where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I use Charpit Method to solve the problem but calculation getting big.  Is there any other method to solve the problem.I think I need some variable transformation which gives me a standard form then I easily solve the problem.

Comment: What's differential about it?

Comment: An equation does not become a PDE when the symbol $p$ appears in it.

Comment: What's the boundary condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment:
The PDE you are asked to solve is
\begin{align}
0&=F(x,y,z,p,q)=z+\underbrace{x\,p-x^2 y\, q^2-x^3 p\, q}_{\textstyle(*)}\,,\quad p=\partial_xz\,,\quad q=\partial_yz\,.
\end{align}
[Charpit's method](https://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Emate/misc/charpits_method_compl_int.pdf) is
to calculate all partial derivatives of  $F$ (that is $F_x$ and so on) and deduce
a relationship between some of the variables $x,y,p,q$ from the equations
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{F_p}&=\frac{dy}{F_q}=\frac{dz}{pF_p+qF_q}=-\frac{dp}{F_x+pF_z}=-\frac{dq}{F_y+qF_z}\,.
\end{align}
This looks nearly impossible here.

The underbraced term is of the form
$$
(*)=x\,p\,-x^2q\,(y\,q+x\,p)\,.
$$
With the variable transformation
\begin{align}
X&=x\,,\quad Y=\frac yx\,,\quad y=XY\,,
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
p&=P\,X_x+Q\,Y_x=P-\frac{QY}{X}\,,&
q&=P\,X_y+Q\,Y_y=\frac QX\,,\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
x\,p&=X\,P-Y\,Q\,,\quad y\,q=Y\,Q\,,\quad y\,q+x\,p=X\,P\,,&
x^2\,q&=X\,Q\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
(*)=X\,P-Y\,Q-X^2\,P\,Q\,
\end{align}
which transforms the PDE into a much simpler one. Please try Charpit's method from here.

Comment: But I use all common veriable transformation but no one brings the PDE more standard form